# How to position a HTML element exactly where you want it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/5mkt6ucr/

```
<div class="pwordCheck">
            <label>Password </label> <input type="password" id="pword" data-placement="right" title="" data-original-title="Password must be more than 6 characters long" class="mytooltip"><br>
            <label>Confirm Password </label>  <input type="password" id="confpword" onkeyup="passwordValidation(); return false;" data-placement="left" title="" data-original-title="Passwords must match" class="mytooltip">
            <span id="themessage" class="themessage"></span><br> 
        </div>
```

as can be seen in my jsfiddle, once you start typing into password and confirm password a message pops up. however this messages shunts the input field to the left. i was wondering how do you position this so it pops up without altering the field. i have tried doing position: absolute/relative etc and have tried altering the width so i felt like it was squashing it in. to no avail. 
anyone got a solution?
thanks

Comment: you need to change the `position:relative` of `#firstform span` to `position:absolute;`

Comment: fair play, not sure why that didnt work earlier. how did that work? and it does a weird thing where it takes the 'search magnifying glass icon' and places it at the top of the page?

Comment: it is because you are point the `span` from css i suggest you to give a class to the error message `span` and than style it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change your css property of *#firstform span* from *relative* to ***absolute***
as

```
#firstform span{
    position: absolute;
}
```

**update:**

**fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/5mkt6ucr/14/

for the search button image add a property as

```
.glyphicon-search
{
   position:relative !important;
}
```

Comment: You broke the icon of the search button

Comment: @ObeseOctopus check out new updated fiddle, its fixed now.

Comment: @ShaminderSAujla why use `!important`  if we can solve that problem by taking class of that span

Comment: @Amitsingh try removing !important. you will get the answer, tried on firefox, opera, ucbrowser

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't solve the problem with css but maybe it's ok.
I added '< br >'

```
}else if (password1.value == confpword1.value){
        confpword1.style.backgroundColor = gbc;
        themsg.style.backgroundcolor 
        themsg.innerHTML = "<br>Passwords match";
    }else{
        confpword1.style.backgroundColor = bbc;
        themsg.style.color = gc;
        themsg.innerHTML = "<br>Passwords do not match";        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You use text-align:center;

If you remove the `text-align:center;` from `#firstform` you'll see that everything looks fine.

To center the `#firstform` try something with:

`margin: 0 auto;` 
or
 `left:-50%;` + `margin-left:-(width/50)`

please note that for these centering options your element needs a hard width, so you cant use `width:100%;`.

Answer (score 1):

Your **CSS**

```
#firstform span{
    position: absolute;
}
```

Just change your **CSS** like this...

```
#firstform .themessage{
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to changes in CSS position code. you can do with this code also. Your jsfiddle code was Edited. [**Click Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/gaurangnil/5mkt6ucr/17/)

```
if(confpword1.value == ''){
        confpword1.style.background = empty;
    }else if (password1.value == ''){
        confpword1.style.background = empty;
    }else if (password1.value == confpword1.value){
        confpword1.style.backgroundColor = gbc;
        themsg.style.backgroundcolor 
        themsg.innerHTML = '<div class="passerror">Passwords match<div>';
}else{
    confpword1.style.backgroundColor = bbc;
    themsg.style.color = gc;
    themsg.innerHTML = '<div class="passerror">Passwords do not match</div>';       
}
```

Comment: adding n number of &emsp; is not a gud idea i think

Comment: @ShaminderSAujla then just use `<div>` either use `<br/>` and `&emsp;`